# Oracle DDL export

Tags: oracle, hsqldb, ddl

I am trying to recreate an oracle database in an HSQL database.
this is to enable better unit testing on the local developer systems.

What I need to know is is there anything tool/command I can use in the oracle server/client, that can provide me all the DDL commands for all the objects (tables, synonyms, views etc) in the oracle database.

I am planning to go through the created DDL commands and try to convert these commands into HSQL compatible commands.

Is it possible?

Any suggestions will be welcome.

system information:

```
Oracle DB: Oracle enterprise server 11g R2. 
HSQL DB: hsql 2.2.9
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`DBMS_METADATA` package](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_metada.htm) along with the data dictionary to generate the DDL for your objects.  For example, to generate the DDL for every table in a schema

```
declare
  l_ddl clob;
begin
  for t in (select * from user_tables)
  loop
    l_ddl := dbms_metadata.get_ddl( 'TABLE', t.table_name, USER );
    <<do something with l_ddl>>
  end loop;
end;
```

Are you sure that it makes sense to test with a completely different database than what you're really going to deploy to?  Even if you translate the DDL to the closest analogue, it seems very likely that you'll get different results for some tests depending on the database you're connected to.  Are you sure that you can't install Oracle (potentially Oracle XE if your concerns are primarily about licensing) on the developer's machines?

Comment: thanks. Actually the intent of the conversion is to get the functional test completely working on a portable and embeddable database. This is for my Unit testing, across a very large team, where having oracle express edition on each individual user is not a feasibility. Plus, a small, portable DB like HSQL can make the JUNIT testing process much independent.

Comment: @Ayusman - But then your unit tests aren't testing that your code will actually work once you deploy it to an Oracle database which rather defeats the purpose of having a suite of unit tests. Heck, when you move from one version of Oracle to another, you presumably do a full round of testing on the new version because sometimes things that worked in one version don't work in another.  Going from one database engine to another opens up a world of potential failures. If you have developers writing code that is going to run in Oracle, it seems very odd not to test on Oracle.

Comment: yes Justin you have valid point on database porting issues. But the result I am trying to accomplish by having a junit test db is (1) run the test cases with a complete set of data which is not necessarily a prod like data but a full functional data set for my application features (2) share copy of the DB with a big team so that they can modify/tweak the DB as to create problem scenarios (3) a dump of such an HSQL db can be stored and recreated on local environment without having to go through DBA route. And again ur views are valid. My test suite runs on oracle during cruise control build.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few products that can help.

OpenSource:
http://www.liquibase.org/manual/formatted_sql_changelogs

Commercial with free trial:
http://www.devart.com/dbforge/oracle/schemacompare/new-export-oracle-schema.html

If you use a tool that is generally designed for use with Oracle databases only, you may get quite a lot of non-standard Oracle DDL that needs converting. A cross platform tool is more likely to reduce the work.

When HSQLDB is used in the ORA compatibility mode, it can translate some Oracle types in the DDL to a similar SQL Standard type. So the types may not pose a problem.

Comment: I have tried liquibase, but it seems the it can not get me the DDL for some of the oracle objects. Though I am not exactly sure which of these oracle objects liquibase can not export. But I will look at the devart site. Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

One open source inactive project do exact same thing.

http://schemamule.sourceforge.net/index.html

Comment: I have forked this and have added additional features as well as mavenizing. See https://github.com/benlamonica/oracle2hsqldb